I want my macro to find all words (in a certain unformatted document) that start with a certain string ("yyy") give these words a different formatting
I want to find all words (in a certain unformatted document) that start with a certain string ("yyy") and give these words a different formatting.
The following VBA-code executes once and then stops. I tried to use a loop, but it did not work.
Can anyone please help me with this problem?
Sub Macro1()
'   Do Until ActiveDocument.Range.End       --- this loop does not work ---
    
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = "yyy"
    Selection.Find.Execute
'   Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Font.Size = 20
    Selection.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdGray25
    End With
'   Loop
End Sub


Selection.Find.Execute returns true if the the find operation is successful. You can build a loop around that.
dim wasFound as Boolean
do
   wasFound = Selection.Find.Execute()
   'more stuff
loop while wasFound

(Documentation)
